# ListView renders multiple widget after calling setState in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have this function that shows a showDialog widget with a child of ListView builder based on a list

My problem is that when I add items to the list using setState(In my case, stateSetter), the ListView re-render duplicated widget.

As I'm debugging the issue, I noticed that it only happens when I'm using a Column/Row widget.

//result in listview
(1st setState)

```
    Product1
```

(2nd setState)

```
    Product1
    Product2
    Product1
    Product2
```

Code below:

```
    void showProductDialog() {
    //variable for ListViewBuilder
    List<Product> _products = [];

    showDialog(
    //..context,builder, etc...
    return AlertDialog(
    //..title, etc..
    content: StatefulBuilder(builder: (ctx, stateSetter) {
     return Container(
      child:Column(
      children: [
       ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _products.length,
        itemBuilder:(ctx,index) {
         //problem occurs
         return Column(children: _products.map((e) => Text(e.name)).toList()
       }
    ),
    RaisedButton.icon(
    onPressed: () {
     stateSetter((){
       // adding new item to list
       _products.add(Products(...))
     })
     ...
```

Any help and suggestion will be much appreciated!
Thankyou!

EDIT: The list variable are behaving properly, when I print all the items, all of it are unique. The duplicate issue was only occured on rendering the items to Column

EDIT 2: The purpose of using column widget is to print data somehow properly.
Example of what to expect:

```
    Product1
    Name: Sample name
    Price: $1
    
    Product2
    Name: Sample 2
    Price: $2
```

Comment: add key to your column

Comment: I already done that, sadly didnt fix my issue

Comment: Can you post some sample Products data so that we can replicate it . Maybe I Think the issues is with using the map inside the listview it is iterating the every time time creating a duplicates.

Comment: Updated the post. ps. Issue occurs even in list of string

Answer (score 0):

i cant see the whole code but try this
Just clear the list before adding again
use

```
stateSetter((){
       // clear the list to prevent duplication
       _products.clear(),

       // adding new item to list
       _products.add(Products(...))
     })
```

Comment: Sorry I just uploaded a simplified ver. because my code was too long, what part do you need? Also, I dont want to clear items  to my list because I need to display all the items on the list both previous and new added data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my problem. I did not read your request carefully

My solution:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _products.length,
  itemBuilder:(_,index) {
    return Text(_products[index].name); // remove Column
 }
),
```

Comment: Yes apparently this is the only solution I discovered. Thats why I included in my post the result of my process in debugging. If I want to show multiple data I just added \n in inside the quote eg 'Product1\nSweetLevel: 5'. This may work but I dont think that it will be appropriate. Any idea why this is happening?